# Why can't you resize the Windows Environment Variable box?

Tags: environment-variables

Recently having to set my PATH environment variable installing the JDK, I found it quite annoying that the box where you set environment variables was not re-sizable, and had was generally quite horrible to edit.

Aside from MS just not making this more UI-friendly, I was wondering if this was built as such for a reason, or if we are hanging onto some legacy code that is affecting this.

Any ideas?

Comment: Alternatives to the standard dialog are discussed in [Is there a good tool for managing the Windows Environment Variables?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35488/).

Answer (score 7):

I'm going to blow your mind here, but as of Windows 10 build 10565, this window is finally resizeable.

https://plus.google.com/+ArtemRussakovskii/posts/h1En1s5abJs

[image]

Comment: I'm on Windows 10/64 Pro and this isn't the case.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe you'd like this nifty tool I've been using for a while, [**ResizeEnable**](http://www.digitallis.co.uk/pc/ResizeEnable/). It allows you to resize windows that are normally not resizable:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I don't get it at all. It's completely unnecessarily painful.

Use [Windows Path Editor](http://www.softpedia.com/get/System/System-Miscellaneous/Path-Editor.shtml) instead. It'll make life a lot easier and less error prone (I realise this doesn't answer your question *per se*, but is offered as general advice!)

Comment: Only edits your path not Environment variables. Try RapidEE for editing environment variables. rapidee.com

Answer (score 1):

Anything that is considered *a dialog* by Windows isn't resizable. And that includes, unfortunatelly, the aforementioned as well.

Answer (score 1):

This is because of the size of the app.
Go to the Display settings and change the size of the app to 150%.
Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

While it indeed may have been built to make power user heads expode everywhere, I find the `setx` command to be a frequently viable way around it, e.g.:

```
setx HOME "%USERPROFILE%"
```